# Javascript: RegExp not working no matter what my expression is

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, I've been using RegExp a number of times but for some reason I cannot get it to work this time. I am trying to test for latitude (0 to +/- 90 degrees). No matter what expression I use, it always returns false. Here's my code:

```
var regexLatitude = new RegExp("^-?([1-8]?[0-9]\.{1}\d{1,6}$|90\.{1}0{1,6}$)");
var status = regexLatitude.test("89.5");
```

I also tried without quotes:

```
var status = regexLatitude.test(89.5);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\` characters are being parsed by the Javascript string literal.

You need to use a regex literal:

```
var regexLatitude = /^-?([1-8]?[0-9]\.{1}\d{1,6}$|90\.{1}0{1,6}$)/;
```

Comment: mellamokb: You're right. I need a double slash. SLaks solution is also good.