# Password validation regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying regexp for password validation

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}$
```

It restricts at least 1 digit, 1 upper and 1 lower case letter, doesn't it?
So why the following results as `true`?

```
(new RegExp('^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}$')).test('aaAAffffaAfDvad')
```

But the next one `false`?

```
(new RegExp('^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}$')).test('aaAA112')
```

Comment: Please don't create limitation on maximum length. There is no real reason for that

Comment: Ditch the number/case requirements and the max length requirement.  They don't work and have never worked.  Also see http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: You can fiddle about with your RegEx on this [site](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php). Never know, you might find something interesting...

Comment: @zerkms thank you for comment. But it is not the main problem I'm sure.

Comment: Love that comic strip @Deestan... So true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your JS console (firebug or other) try this :

```
var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$/
```

then this :

```
var re2 = new RegExp('^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$')
```

then you just check the results... You'll see that in re2 the `\d` is not escaped properly for a regexp but escaped for a string.

EDIT : 
found [Javascript: RegExp not working no matter what my expression is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347384/javascript-regexp-not-working-no-matter-what-my-expression-is?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `\` in `\d` is not escaped correctly:

```
>>> var x = new RegExp('^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$');
>>> x
/^(?=.*d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$/

>>> var x = new RegExp('^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$');
>>> x
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$/
```

You can also utilize this function for proper regexp escaping:

```
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace( /[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&" );
};
var x = new RegExp( RegExp.escape( '^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient way of doing it but quite extensible.

```
requirements = [ /\d/, /[A-Z]/, /[a-z]/, /^.{6,20}$/ ];

function passwordValid( password ) {
    var i = requirements.length;

    while( i-- ) {
        if( !requirements[i].test( password ) ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```