# password and confirm password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, passwords

I want to validate password and confirm password field. Already done validation for password mismatch.Now i want to validate, the user must enter password between 8 to 15 and mixed symbols, characters,numbers

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
<label for="pass">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="pass" class="text" name="your_pass" value="" onblur="passchk()"/>
<label for="c_pass">Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" id="c_pass" class="text" name="your_c_pass" value="" onblur="confirmPass()"/><br>
<span id="error" style="color:#F00;"> </span>
```

JS:

```
function confirmPass() {
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value
    var confPass = document.getElementById("c_pass").value
    if(pass != confPass) {
        //alert('Wrong confirm password !');
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='wrong confirm password';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='';
    }
}


function passchk(){
    alert('hi');

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are dozens of questions regarding password validation with fully developed regexp strings good to go

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password validation regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602645/password-validation-regexp)

Comment: Why do you have a 15 character limit on passwords? That's unnecessarily restrictive, and is often an indication that you're storing passwords in an insecure manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8 to 15 characters which contain only characters, numeric digits, underscore and first character must be a letter

```
function CheckPassword(input)   
{   
    var pass=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{8,15}$/;  
    if(input.value.match(pass))   
    {     
        return true;  
    }  
        else  
    {   
        alert('Password Is Not Valid')  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: it accept 8-15 in alphabets only...error message displayed while enter numeric and symbols

Comment: ^[\w\d]{8,15}$ try this,

or if you want  you password to be started with letter only than try this
^[A-Za-z][\w\d]{8,14}$

Comment: i want mixed combination of password. like EX: dere@12

Comment: ^[A-Za-z].{8,14}$ - first character must be letter and than whatever you want,
read regular expression manuals it will be helpfull to customize it yourself.
http://www.regexr.com/ - great site for learning and testing

Comment: yeah....but what am expecting is not there....multiple combination of password (gdg@87D). it allow user to enter full of alphabets or number

Comment: . in regexp matches everything exept linebreaks, and i tested it matches, any combination that starts with letter and than whatever u want, from 8 to 15 letters length if u want to start passworsd with ( letter than try ^.{8,15}$ , but its wrong approach